# Windows 8 TTF font problems

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, windows, truetype

We are building a small app which produces a `.pdf` out of a TeX document.

Therefore we copied the `pdflatex.exe` (`pdftex.exe`, `pdftex.dll`) and its configs and packages out of TeXlive 2013.

To handle ttf fonts such as 'Verdana' or 'Times New Roman' we also copied `ttf2tfm.exe` to get our metric fonts.

A small batch runs this commands:

```
ttf2tfm fonts/verdana.ttf -p T1-WGL4.enc
ttf2tfm fonts/arial.ttf -p T1-WGL4.enc
copy "fonts\verdana.tfm" verdana.tfm
copy "fonts\arial.tfm" arial.tfm
pdflatex example.tex
```

For each font we have a font definition (`.fd`) file like 'T1arial.fd'.

This runs perfectly with fonts out of  the Windows 7 font directory. Now we are on Windows 8 and we run this commands. Now, the pdf document is full of characters like ▯▯▯▯▯▯. We think this is a encoding problem. But what can we do?

In our log we get

> pdflatex.exe (file fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `[...]`

for each character.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use XeLaTeX, which handles system fonts directly?

Comment: Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead.